# Remove spacing between divs in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am writing a div right now that will hold multiple lines of text but I need to remove the spacing after every text item. Is there a way to do this in CSS?

```css
h3 {
    font-family: BelyDisplay;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 3rem;
    margin-right: 3rem;
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal bold 25px/55px Montserrat;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #F0532D;
    opacity: 1; 
}

h4 {
    font-family: BelyDisplay;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 3rem;
    margin-right: 3rem;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: left;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    opacity: 1; 
    font: normal normal bold 18px/22px Montserrat;
    color: #483735;

.role-text{
    font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
    margin-left: 3rem;
    margin-right: 3rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: left;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    font: normal normal normal 18px/22px Montserrat;
    color: #483735;
}
```

```html
<div class="textbox">
  <span id="close" onclick="this.parentNode.remove(); location.reload(); return false;" class="btn btn-default large">
            <img src="/src/Esc X.svg" height="33" width="33"></img>
        </span>
  <h2>${roleTypes[role]?.title ?? 'none'}</h2>
  <div id="card-div">
    <p class="role-subtitle">${roleTypes[role]?.subtitle ?? 'none'}</p>
    <h3>CHARGE</h3>
    <h4>${roleTypes[role]?.chargesubtitle ?? 'none'}</h4>
    <p class="role-text">${roleTypes[role]?.chargebody ?? 'none'}</p>
    <h3>SCOPE</h3>
    <h4>${roleTypes[role]?.scopesubtitle ?? 'none'}</h4>
    <p class="role-text">${roleTypes[role]?.scopebody ?? 'none'}</p>
    <h3>FORECASTING</h3>
    <h4>${roleTypes[role]?.forecastingsubtitle ?? 'none'}</h4>
    <p class="role-text">${roleTypes[role]?.forecastingbody ?? 'none'}</p>
    <h3>COMMUNICATION + RESPONSIBILITY</h3>
    <h4>${roleTypes[role]?.communicationsubtitle ?? 'none'}</h4>
    <p class="role-text">${roleTypes[role]?.communicationbody ?? 'none'}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently the text shows correctly based on the XD I've been given from UX/UI but the text should be stacked on top of each other with no spacing between them.

Comment: You mean without the vertical margins? `<h3>`, `<h4>` and `<p>` all have vertical margins by default in nearly every browser. If you don't want them set them to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're missing the closing bracket of `h4 {}` (and I doubt you want to style `h4 .role-text`, since `.role-text` is a sibling of `h4`, not a descendant). If you don't close it, `.role-text` rules won't apply.
2. You probably want to apply a top and bottom [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) of `0` to `h3`, `h4` and `p`.
   Most browsers apply vertical margins to them, via user agent stylesheet. There are various ways to disable those style rules (it's called a CSS reset), but I wouldn't recommend it, unless you know what you're doing and you want a completely clean slate. Most of them are decent defaults.

The following should have the desired effect (unless rules with selectors of higher specificity, which you haven't included in the question, are applying):

```css
h3, h4 {
  margin: 0 3rem;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked I ended up doing a margin-top and margin-bottom of -0.5rem and that closed the gaps.

Comment: @Jay, note text lines have a [line height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) in web. By setting negative margins you're overlapping text lines, potentially affecting readability and accessibility. In other words, your letters might touch/overlap. You can visualise this by setting up semi-transparent backgrounds on each element (e.g: `h3,h3,p { background-color: #f003 }`).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```css
h3 {
    font-family: BelyDisplay;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 3rem;
    margin-right: 3rem;
    text-align: left;
    font: normal normal bold 25px/55px Montserrat;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #F0532D;
    opacity: 1; 
}

h4 {
    font-family: BelyDisplay;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 3rem;
    margin-right: 3rem;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: left;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    opacity: 1; 
    font: normal normal bold 18px/22px Montserrat;
    color: #483735;

.role-text{
    font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
    margin-left: 3rem;
    margin-right: 3rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: left;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    font: normal normal normal 18px/22px Montserrat;
    color: #483735;
}
```

```html
<div class="textbox">
  <span id="close" onclick="this.parentNode.remove(); location.reload(); return false;" class="btn btn-default large">
            <img src="/src/Esc X.svg" height="33" width="33"></img>
        </span>
  <h2>${roleTypes[role]?.title ?? 'none'}</h2>
  <div id="card-div">
    <p class="role-subtitle">${roleTypes[role]?.subtitle ?? 'none'}</p>
    <h3>CHARGE</h3>
    <h4>${roleTypes[role]?.chargesubtitle ?? 'none'}</h4>
    <p class="role-text">${roleTypes[role]?.chargebody ?? 'none'}</p>
    <h3>SCOPE</h3>
    <h4>${roleTypes[role]?.scopesubtitle ?? 'none'}</h4>
    <p class="role-text">${roleTypes[role]?.scopebody ?? 'none'}</p>
    <h3>FORECASTING</h3>
    <h4>${roleTypes[role]?.forecastingsubtitle ?? 'none'}</h4>
    <p class="role-text">${roleTypes[role]?.forecastingbody ?? 'none'}</p>
    <h3>COMMUNICATION + RESPONSIBILITY</h3>
    <h4>${roleTypes[role]?.communicationsubtitle ?? 'none'}</h4>
    <p class="role-text">${roleTypes[role]?.communicationbody ?? 'none'}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```